# Silent /d/ or /t/

Tags: phonetics, silent-letters

When a word ending with the /d/ or /t/ sound is pronounced and the next word starts with a consonant, the sounds /d/ or /t/ are silent. For example: *I used to play tennis.*

My question is related to the regular verbs. Consider:

> *I managed to do it.*

If the /d/ sound is silent in this case, this then is like pronunciating *I manage to do it.* The context will decide if the tense is present or past.

Does this stand?

Comment: It is incorrect to say that the letters are not pronounced in this scenario.  They are typically greatly muted, but there is a difference in the pronunciation of "use" and "used" in "This is the racket I use to play tennis" vs "I used to play tennis".  Whether the listener can detect this slight difference, though, depends on a number of factors.

Comment: (In the above, "use" is pronounced '"youzz" while "used" is pronounced "yousst", with no "z" sound.)

Comment: @HotLicks Would you pronounce *I **managed/manage** to do it* both the same?

Comment: That one is a bit tougher.  Probably the distinction would be lost, unless the speaker were making an effort to speak clearly.

Comment: I can't come up with a sentence where *I manage to do* could apply, isn't the past  always used in  *managed to + verb*? Perhaps a better example might be `We manage(d) time`

Comment: @Mari-LouA - I manage to get up at 6am every morning.  Why don't you try it? !!

Comment: @HotLicks *Used* is pronounced differently but not like that: "This is the racket I use to play tennis" and "...used to play tennis" are almost identical (z sound). "This is the racket I used to play tennis with" doesn't have the z sound. The verb is actually different -- one is employment, the other is habit.

Comment: @Dan oh, good one.

Comment: @Mari-LouA - thanks (it's not true mind!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In ordinary speech *all* of the following (and many others similar) are ambiguous - is the speaker meaning present or past?

I like(d) to drink coffee.

I hope(d) to see him.

I manage(d) to get up at 6am.

I promise(d) to buy a dog.

...*etc*...

The ambiguity, potentially, results in a significantly different message.  However, all sentences can be made clear easily by articulating clearly (i.e. incorporating a clear break in sound before "...*to*...").

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I agree that d/t can be lost between consonants in casual speech.  However, I think the loss proceeds by (1) complete assimilation of d/t to the preceding consonant, producing a long consonant, then at a more casual level, (2) shortening the long consonant.  For your example "I managed to do it", I hear a lengthened affricate at the end of "manage", and then at a more casual level, that affricate can be shortened, in case the context makes clear that "manage" should be past tense.